# Откуда пошло слово "стибрить"?

Tags: этимология, жаргон

От какого слова происходит слово "стибрить" (украсть)? От Тибра, что ли?)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ага. Это еще Владимир Владимирович, который совсем лысый, заметил.

Рим - город и стоит на Тибре.
Румыны смотрят, что бы стибрить.

//----**UPD**
Кстати, есть один синоним, так он точно с Пизой связан.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то нет, не связан.

Comment: Правильно будет сказать, что этимология "стибрить" не ясна.

Comment: Возможно, от этой игры слов (конечно, вряд ли авторства В. В.) и произошло слово *"стибрить"*.

Comment: @Валентин . Нет тут никакого каламбура . Смотрите мой ответ ниже .

Answer (score 2):

Замечу, что используется также слово "подтибрить".

> — Куда ты дела, разбойница, бумагу?
> — Ей-богу, барин, не видывала, опричь небольшого лоскутка, которым изволили прикрыть рюмку.
> — А вот я по глазам вижу, что подтибрила.
> — Да на что ж бы я подтибрила? Ведь мне проку с ней никакого; я грамоте не знаю.
> [Н. В. Гоголь. Мертвые души](https://klassika.ru/read.html?proza/gogol/dushi.txt&page=24#:%7E:text=%2D%20%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%2C,%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B6%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%3F)

Возможно, это от "ты брал"?
Так же, как "присвоить" — сделать своим.

Answer (score 1):

Давно-давно, ещё веков поболее пяти до нашей эры, существовало на южном Кавказе государство Урарту. Считалось, что урарты были предками армян, однако антропологические исследования урартских захоронений выявили в них славянские типы. Удалось прочесть кое-какие слова урартов. И среди них слово "ТИБИРИТИ" в значении "БРАТЬ/ЗАБИРАТЬ". Вот это и есть древняя основа слова "СТИБРИТЬ".
Обнаруживаются и другие совпадения языка урартов со словами русского языка. Мы говорим *небо синее*, а на языке урартов *сюне* означало *небо*; урарты месяц (Луну) называли *ясунь*, а мы говорим *месяц ясный*; есть и другие соответствия. К сожалению, у меня не сохранился этот исторический сборник "Дорогами тысячелетий" (и номер выпуска не помню), где была статья про язык урартов. Но про ТИБИРИТИ — СТИБРИТЬ запомнил чётко.

Answer (score 0):

От немецкого stibitzen - слова из старого студенческого жаргона.

Comment: А "старые студенты" какого времени так хорошо немецкий знали, что всю фонетику переврали?

Answer (score 0):

от немецкого глагола Stieben, что значит украсть